# Add multiple markers on GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am new to Google Maps and I want to add multiple markers to GMSMapView and infoWindow.

### My code below

```
   for Prop: Property in properties
    {
        var latStr = Prop.lat as NSString
        var latDbl : Double  = Double(latStr.intValue)
        var langStr = Prop.lang as NSString
        var langDbl : Double = Double(langStr.intValue)

        var marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDbl,langDbl )
        println(marker.position)
        marker.flat = true
        marker.title = Prop.buildingName as String
        marker.snippet = Prop.address as String
        marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        marker.map = googleMapView

    }

 googleMapView.delegate = self
```

Can some one please let me know what I am doing wrong or someone can edit my code and show me the correct way?

Comment: It seems like you override maker and ended up with 1 marker on the map? Where do you define position and london in your code?

Comment: thanyaj, have updated my code ..still it is not showing ...

Comment: dhaval, do you get 1 marker or no marker at all on the map?

Comment: No, I am not getting any markers

Comment: Sorry that I can't think of anything obvious from the code snippet you provide. There is a few thing to set up Google Maps to work in the project. This web site explains it well and might be helpful.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift

Comment: i took this example ...but for one marker it is coming right...but in array is having an issue

Comment: done..it is resolved...just change the delegate position on bottom to TOP..

Comment: ah.. that makes sense now.

Comment: @dhavalshah what do you mean by changing delegate position on bottom to TOP?